# How to start a program in the background

Tags: shell, sudo, background-process

The program **Boblight** does not run in background. There is no noticeable difference between executing

```
sudo boblightd
```

and

```
sudo boblightd&
```

How can I solve this problem that the console will not block further inputs?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/boblight/boblightd-for-raspberry-master $ sudo boblightd
Boblightd 2.0 (optimized version for raspberry) (c) 2013 Speedy1985 and Heven)
(InitLog)                       start of log /root/.boblight/boblightd.log
(PrintFlags)                    starting boblightd
(CConfig::LoadConfigFromFile)   opening /etc/boblight.conf
(CConfig::CheckConfig)          checking config lines
(CConfig::CheckConfig)          config lines valid
(CConfig::BuildConfig)          building config
(CConfig::BuildConfig)          built config successfully
(main)                          starting devices
(CClientsHandler::Process)      opening listening TcpSocket on *:19333
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: starting with output "/dev/spidev0.0"
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: setting up
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: setup succeeded


pi@raspberrypi ~/boblight/boblightd-for-raspberry-master $ sudo boblightd&
[1] 2289
pi@raspberrypi ~/boblight/boblightd-for-raspberry-master $
Boblightd 2.0 (optimized version for raspberry) (c) 2013 Speedy1985 and Heven)
(InitLog)                       start of log /root/.boblight/boblightd.log
(PrintFlags)                    starting boblightd
(CConfig::LoadConfigFromFile)   opening /etc/boblight.conf
(CConfig::CheckConfig)          checking config lines
(CConfig::CheckConfig)          config lines valid
(CConfig::BuildConfig)          building config
(CConfig::BuildConfig)          built config successfully
(main)                          starting devices
(CClientsHandler::Process)      opening listening TcpSocket on *:19333
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: starting with output "/dev/spidev0.0"
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: setting up
(CDevice::Process)              ambilight: setup succeeded
```

Comment: Say: `sudo boblightd > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: If you are not doing this for learning purpose then use `dmenu`. It is simple and does the job pretty well.

Answer (score 22):

The `[1] 2289` after your background command shows it worked, and was indeed put into the background.

But the output of your command will still go to the terminal, unless you redirect. Here is the comprehensive way to do that:

```
sudo boblightd >std.txt 2>err.txt &
```

If you want both stdout and stderr to go to the same file:

```
sudo boblightd >std.txt 2>&1 &
```

And, of course, if you don't care about the output of either or both streams, you can send to `/dev/null` instead of a filename.

```
sudo boblightd >/dev/null 2>err.txt &
```

(that example throws away standard output, but keeps stderr, just in case something goes wrong.)

---

**UPDATE**

The above is based on no knowledge of what boblightd is. I see in another answer it has a daemon mode, so that should be used instead in this case.

BTW, the above assumes `sudo` will not prompt for a password, and that you will not close the terminal window. For the former, I personally normally use `sudo bash` then, would type `boblightd >std.txt 2>err.txt &`. Another way is to do `sudo ls` or some harmless command to make sure the access gets cached.

For the latter, `nohup` is the magic command to make sure it stays running even after you Leave The Building. It would go after the `sudo` and before the actual command. E.g. `sudo nohup boblightd >std.txt 2>err.txt &`. Or `sudo bash` then `nohup boblightd >std.txt 2>err.txt &`, then `exit` (to leave the root shell).

Comment: It is also important to note that if `sudo` tries to prompt for the password, it'll fail because background processes cannot read STDIN.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I had just answered on the immediate problem in the question, but as this is getting some attention I have updated with mention of password prompting and nohup.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use nohup command like this:

```
nohup sudo boblightd &
```

this will put the output of your command to nohup.out file in current directory.

Also you can use screen command like this :
first create a screen :

```
screen -S your-sreen-name
```

then run your command:

```
sudo boblightd
```

To save the screen and return to the terminal, type <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> is the hint for `screen` that you want to do something and <kbd>D</kbd> then "d"etaches from the session without stopping it).

restore your screen :

```
screen -d -r your-screen-name
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to redirect stdout and stderr to something else than their defaults to hide them. @devnull's comment shows how to do this. That's a first step.

If you simply use `&` to detach your program, it will be killed automaticaly when you logout. That's probably not what you want. You'll have to use the `nohup` command to prevent this:

`nohup sudo boblightd > boblight.out 2> boblight.err < /dev/null &`

Note that `sudo` will probably ask for a password: it won't get any, and you won't notice it's asking you for one, as every output/input is redirected. You have different solutions to achieve this anyway:

- Run a `sudo` command before, `sudo` will save your password. That's the quick'n'dirty way.
- Remove the `&`, give `sudo` the password, then send the process to background with <kbd>CTRL + Z</kbd>.
- Can also configure sudo to not ask the password for this specific user and executable couple. Be aware that it could be a possible security breach, …

Comment: Is it better to have the nohup before of after the `sudo`? How does `sudo` get it's password when you run it under `nohup`?

Comment: Well, that's a good point: it won't. You have multiple solutions here: run a sudo command before, sudo will save your password. That's the quick'n'dirty way. Another one would be to remove the `&`, give `sudo` the password, then send the process to background with `ctrl + z`. You can also configure `sudo` to not ask the password for this specific user and executable couple.

Comment: I normally do `sudo bash`, then run the `nohup` command from inside the new shell.

Comment: Actually it is incorrect that if you only use `&` do background the process that it'll be killed on logout. Only if bash is killed with a SIGHUP will it then SIGHUP your program. But logging out does not cause a SIGHUP. If you type `logout` or use CTRL+D, bash will exit and leave the process running. SIGHUP is sent when you close the terminal emulator in a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

**Boblightd**

In the case of *boblightd* the output sent to stderr is already captured in it's log file (defaults to *~/.boblight/boblightd.log*), so this doesn't need to be captured and can be discarded.  Also, boblight doesn't fork by default but can be made to do by include the **-f** in the command.

I suggest you try the following:

```
sudo boblightd -f >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

(details [from the project documentation](https://code.google.com/p/boblight/wiki/boblightd))

**More generally**

Processes started from the shell will terminate when the shell exits.  As others have pointed out using <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> while running a process in the foreground returns control to the shell.  However, the process is placed in a **stopped state** at this point.  The `bg`  command  will be needed to get the process running again but stay in background. It requires either a process id or the job number (as usual job numbers are prefixed with a %), so using your second example you would issue either

```
bg %1
```

or

```
bg 2289
```

The process will now be running in the background but is still attached to the shell. The link to the shell can be severed using the `disown` command, which saves the confusion with nohup/sudo.  As with `bg`, `disown` requires only the process id or job number

e.g.

```
disown 2289
```

You can now exit the shell safely as if you had run the process with the `nohup` command

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer is pretty much laid out in comment already. I felt like it would be good to post a little bit of explanation on it as an actual answer.

So the way to go is:  `sudo boblightd > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

There are 3 important parts here. Most important is `&` at the end of line. It makes the shell not wait for command to end before giving back control. It also takes out the standard input from keyboard. It puts the job into background.

But this still would leave the output back into console. To prevent this there is `>` symbol which redirects the standard output (to `/dev/null` in this case).

At this point you can still get output from called command get to screen. This would be the standard error. So lastly there is `2>&1` magic. This redirects output from the standard error stream to the standard output.

`2` and `1` come from standard file descriptors. `0` would be `stdin`, `1` - stdout, `2` - stderr.

You could redirect output to a file if you need it.

There are command designed to interact with jobs in back ground. `jobs` and `fg`.

You could also play with more advanced solutions such as `screen` command if needed.