# difference between "ls –alR /" and "ls –alR / &"?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

What is the difference between "ls –alR /" and "ls –alR / &"? I seem to get the same out put. but the & sign i think should run it in background?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it's not run in the background? `(sleep 3; ls –alR /) &

Comment: ok i se now it runs in backround so it means that is the differece then, first one runs foreground and the second in backround right?

Comment: Other answers should cover this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101160/how-to-start-a-program-in-the-background

Comment: Both will print output to terminal , so for shorter actions there is no need to run them as a background process

Comment: @Jeyanthinath `ls -R /` is not a short action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running in the background still means the output goes to the terminal by default. The difference is that you type other commands while the program is running. Obviously this will be difficult with programs like `ls` that produce a lot of output.  Try this:

```
ls -alR / >ls_files &
```

You will be able to do other things while `ls` is running. The first time you press enter after `ls` is finished, you will get a message like:

```
[1]+  Done                    ls -alR / >ls_files
```

All the output will now be in the `ls_files` file.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is simple: with ampersand (`&`) execution of your program is sent to background and while it is happening, you can execute other commands.

As `ls` command takes only short time to run, you don't really notice it. It could be easier illustrated with `sleep` command and bash script.

In example I set it to `sleep` (wait) for 5 seconds. This also works same way in terminal as in BASH scripts.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5s
echo hello
```

The `echo hello` line will be executed only after 5 seconds.

Now if you do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5s &
echo hello
```

The `echo hello` line will be executed straight away, without waiting 5 seconds for `sleep` to finish.